# Connecting two separate machines to the same network

Tags: 12.04, networking, virtualbox, hadoop

I'm using Hadoop to do some data analysis for a university project. My university has kindly given me access to a Virtual Machine, which I access through a given IP address using PuTTY in Windows 8. Once connected, the system is running Ubuntu 64bit.

Before I put anything on this system I am testing it on my own laptop. I have Oracle's VirtualBox and a Ubuntu 64 bit installation on it.

As my "main work" is being done on the Virtual Machine the university has given me access to, thus far I'm using Hadoop on a single cluster (defying the whole point of the "big data analysis" part of my project). Is there a way for me to connect that virtual machine to my VirtualBox version of Ubuntu to at least demonstrate a cluster of two nodes, or is this impossible as they are not on the same network?

Answer (score 0):

The two Hadoop servers don't need to be on the same local network. If you assign a routable ip address to your local Hadoop vm (possibly using [bridged networking](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged)) can you ping each server?

```
local_hadoop$ ping remote_hadoop
```

and

```
remote_hadoop$ ping local_hadoop
```

If so you are good to go. If not you can create a vpn between the two servers.

I recommend [OpenVPN](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenVPN). It is easy to setup. Configure the remote Hadoop as the OpenVPN server. Your local Hadoop vm as a client. Use pre-shared keys for simplicity. Once configured the two Hadoop vm will be on a virtual local network.